# Can database execution plan be reused when parameter count in *IN* clause changes?

Tags: sql, sql-execution-plan, query-planner

If a query is executed with 10 parameters in an IN clause, and then the same query is executed again but with 20 parameters, can the database server reuse the execution plan from the first run, or is a fresh execution plan having to be created each time?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Our product supports both MSSQL server and Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick check in SQL Server and it looks like each query did indeed receive its own query plan when I added/removed values from the `IN` clause.

This code will show you the query plans currently cached. You can adjust the check on `text` to narrow it down to your own specific queries and then see if new rows show up as you execute additional versions of the queries.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    text,
    *
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS CP
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CP.plan_handle) ST
WHERE
    text LIKE 'select * from dbo.My_Table where%'
```